# How to split a string into different columns in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have looked at multiple stack overflow questions similar to this, for example, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56924642/how-to-split-pandas-string-column-into-different-rows) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/how-to-split-a-dataframe-string-column-into-two-columns). However, my situation is a bit more tedious.

I have column consisting of the following strings

```
 lineup
0 'FLEX Nick Mullens FLEX Raheem Mostert FLEX Deebo Samuel FLEX Cole Beasley FLEX Jordan Reed CPT Robbie Gould'
1 'FLEX Nick Mullens FLEX Brandon Aiyuk FLEX Cole Beasley FLEX Tyler Bass FLEX Robbie Gould CPT Raheem Mostert'
2 'FLEX Josh Allen FLEX Stefon Diggs FLEX Cole Beasley FLEX Devin Singletary FLEX Richie James CPT Bills'
...
```

I would like to transform that string into multiple rows, like so:

```
     FLEX1           FLEX2         FLEX3          FLEX4           FLEX5         CPT
0 Nick Mullens  Raheem Mostert  Deebo Samuel  Cole Beasley     Jordan Reed   Robbie Gould
1 Nick Mullens  Brandon Aiyuk   Cole Beasley  Tyler Bass       Robbie Gould  Raheem Mostert
2 Josh Allen    Stefon Diggs    Cole Beasley  Devin Singletary Richie James  Bills
```

So, I would like to expand the FLEX and CPT into separate columns, and the following name should be placed in the according column.

I know how to use `str.split()`, but I'm not sure how to turn part of the string into new columns. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `str.slit` with `expand`:

```
df.lineup.str.split('FLEX|CPT',expand=True)
```